# Надо поэлементо сложить и вычесть трехмерные массивы 3x3(и найти среднее всех элементов)

Tags: javascript

Написал вот такой вот код, вроде все приавильно, но в консоле пустые массивы. Помогите разобраться, что не так

```js
let arr = [
                [1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9],
            ];

            let arr2 = [
                [1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9],
            ];


function Massives(arr, arr2){

                

                function ArrSum(arr, arr2){

                    let ArrSum = [
                        [],
                        [],
                        [],
                    ];

                    for(i=0; i<arr.lenght; i++){
                        let PodArr = arr[i];
                        let PodArr2 = arr2[i];
                        for(k=0; k < PodArr.lenght; k++){
                            let sum = PodArr[k];
                            let sum2 = PodArr2[k];
                            let endSum = sum + sum2;
                            ArrSum[i].push(endSum);
                            
                        }
                    }
                    return ArrSum;

                };



                function ArrSub(arr, arr2){

                let ArrSub = [
                    [],
                    [],
                    [],
                ];
                    for(i=0; i<arr.lenght; i++){
                        let PodArr = arr[i];
                        let PodArr2 = arr2[i];
                        for(k=0; k < PodArr.lenght; k++){
                            let sub = PodArr[k];
                            let sub2 = PodArr2[k];
                            let endSub = sub - sub2;
                            ArrSub[i].push(endSub);
                            
                        }
                    }
                    return ArrSub;

                };


                function ArrMid(arr, arr2){
                    for(i=0; i<arr.lenght; i++){
                        let PodArr = arr[i];
                        let PodArr2 = arr2[i];
                        for(k=0; k < PodArr.lenght; k++){
                            let mid = PodArr[k];
                            let mid2 = PodArr2[k];
                            var EMid =+ mid + mid2;
                            let endMid = EMid/(PodArr.lenght * arr.lenght);
                            return endMid;
                        }
                    }
                };

                
                console.log(ArrSum(arr, arr2));
                console.log(ArrSub(arr, arr2));
                console.log(ArrMid(arr, arr2));
            

                
            }

            console.log(Massives(arr, arr2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимательнее надо

lenght -> length

Comment: спасибо